# create transaction

Tags: daemon

I am trying to transfer 0.1 monero from one account to another
facing this problem

2018-03-09 22:57:27.624 [RPC0]  INFO    wallet.wallet2  src/wallet/wallet2.cpp:3693 0 unlocked outputs of size 0.080000000000
2018-03-09 22:57:27.624 [RPC0]  ERROR   wallet.wallet2  src/wallet/wallet2.cpp:3695 num_outs == 0. THROW EXCEPTION: error::wallet_internal_error
2018-03-09 22:57:27.624 [RPC0]  WARN    net.http    src/wallet/wallet_errors.h:707  /DISTRIBUTION-BUILD/src/wallet/wallet2.cpp:3695:N5tools5error21wallet_internal_errorE: histogram reports no unlocked outputs for 80000000000, not even ours

Comment: 2018-03-09 23:07:38.868 [RPC0] ERROR net contrib/epee/include/storages/portable_storage_from_json.h:173 Wrong JSON character at: e+21}],"mixin":4,"unlock_time":0,"payment_id":0}}
2018-03-09 23:07:38.872 [RPC0] ERROR net contrib/epee/include/storages/portable_storage_from_json.h:368 Failed to parse json, what: Wrong JSON character at: e+21}],"mixin":4,"unlock_time":0,"payment_id":0}}

Comment: histogram reports no unlocked outputs for 70000000000, not even ours